# Power 3.3v board using analog pin

Tags: arduino

What would be the reasons not to use one of the analog pins, set at 3.3v, to power a child board running at 3.3v?

I suspect this is bad, but can't figure out why...

Obviously I'm using a nano board that doesn't have a 3.3v pin...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arduino Nano HAS a 3.3V Output.

http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano

And why is it bad idea to use analogWrite to provide power? Because it doesn't exactly provide constant 3.3V. Arduino uses PWM to provide semi-analog output, and it works like this:

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM

It might be good for LED, but not for a board - you'd get some pretty weird results, most likely a reset every time voltage drops down to zero.

Comment: Sorry I meant Pro mini. Thanks for the answer. PWM definitely bad as power source ;) Would you recommend using a voltage divider on a digital pin then?

Comment: I don't think you have a choice, but make sure you'll get enough current. Or just get Arduino Nano :)

Comment: Thanks. What's the nominal current of a dgital pin? 50 mA?

Comment: I'm not sure, better check on [arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc). Personally I only own Uno.

Comment: 40 mA max per pin and 200mA max overall

Answer (score 2):

Even if the Arduino had true analogue outputs (as opposed to PWM as noted elsewhere) it's very unlikely that it would be stable enough to power another digital device reliably. There will typically be significant noise and some error, and there could be spikes and drops when other peripherals and outputs are used.

Variations like that are often OK in communication signals, because components like triggers and comparators etc. can help filter it out. If the supply voltage is noisy though then it will throw everything else off, and could trigger false edge/level events. You'd really need a regulator to cope with that, which would make the analogue output redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. PWM definitely bad as power source ;)